How does meitools driver write structure information into intel ME (PCI device)?
I came across a Github repository: meitools. It is a forked repository from the original repository, which was built by some researchers that discovered a vulnerability within intel ME. Here there's a video
You can access intel ME through PCI, and it's posible to send some commands to this device. For example: let's say command 0x9 configures intel AMT, then you would have to send 0x9 + AMT configuration data
There are two problems.
1 - Meitools includes a driver (which is supposed to do the IO work). AMTActivator.exe calls deviceiocontrol() and then the MEI driver dispatches the call. However, even though I don't know much about Windows 10 drivers, I can't see any line of code that actually writes info into intel ME MMIO. I just notice an interesting line of code at mei/main.cpp:
NTSTATUS CtlDispatch(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObject, IN PIRP pIrp)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pDeviceObject);

    // Retrieve the stack locaton of current request
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION pIrpStack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(pIrp);

    // Process the request
    switch (pIrpStack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode)
    {

    case IOCTL_MEI_AMTHI_SET_IPV4:
    {
        if (g_MeiContext != NULL)
        {
            // Retrieve the location of the system buffer
            PREQUEST_AMTHI_SET_IPV4 AmtSetIpv4 = (PREQUEST_AMTHI_SET_IPV4) pIrp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

            UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(AmtSetIpv4);

            // Specify the bytes count to be returned
            pIrp->IoStatus.Information = sizeof(REQUEST_AMTHI_SET_IPV4);
        }

        break; // IOCTL_MEI_AMTHI_SET_IPV4
    }

    case IOCTL_MEI_AMTHI_INIT:
    {
        if (g_MeiContext != NULL)
        {
            // Retrieve the location of the system buffer
            PREQUEST_AMTHI_INIT AmtInit = (PREQUEST_AMTHI_INIT) pIrp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

            UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(AmtInit);

            // Specify the bytes count to be returned
            pIrp->IoStatus.Information = sizeof(REQUEST_AMTHI_INIT);
        }

        break; // IOCTL_MEI_AMTHI_INIT
    }

    case IOCTL_MEI_AMTHI_UNCONFIGURE:
    {
        if (g_MeiContext != NULL)
        {
            // Retrieve the location of the system buffer
            PREQUEST_AMTHI_UNCONFIGURE AmtUnconfigure = (PREQUEST_AMTHI_UNCONFIGURE)pIrp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

            UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(AmtUnconfigure);

            // Specify the bytes count to be returned
            pIrp->IoStatus.Information = sizeof(REQUEST_AMTHI_UNCONFIGURE);
        }

        break; // IOCTL_MEI_AMTHI_UNCONFIGURE
    }

    default:
        break;

    }


    // Complete the request
    pIrp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    IoCompleteRequest(pIrp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);


    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

But this piece of code just loads transfered information from AMTActivator.exe DeviceIoControl() and then returns some structure sizes.
2 - AFAIK, it's necessary to send a command before sending the actual data, so intel ME knows what data it is receiving.  Commands groups are defined at mei/mei.h, but they aren't referencied in any file.
This tool works (I haven't tested myself, but researches executed AMTActivator.exe at their talk), so... Maybe Windows is able to identify what intel ME structure is being referenced and it writes to an specific MMIO address?
Even if that's true, the driver only stores some data in variables. How does it send data to PCI MMIO?

This code doesn't do anything; perhaps it was created as a placeholder and the functional code wasn't added until after this repository was forked.
